# Images missing on front-end

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-images, migration, media-images

I've been migrating products from Magento 1.7 to 2.1 using a series of scripts I've written.

The image migration stage appeared to work correctly - the images were copied into their relevant directories, and show up in the back-end when you edit a product.

However, they don't appear on the front end, which just shows a single placeholder image. I've tried clearing the cache, reindexing, deploying static files, using different themes, all to no avail.

Has anybody else had this problem and found a solution?

Edit: I tried adding a product manually through the admin interface, and it did appear on the product page.

Comment: Does images appear in magento admin product grid..?

Comment: They do, Rizwan. They appear throughout the admin interface as expected.

Comment: And when u edit the product .. In images section of product .. Thumb,small,and main image is set for the product?

Comment: Yep, they're all set correctly and all of the images are displayed and can be reordered and saved.

Comment: I have an issue like yours .. Mistake I m did that product is saved in default .. And product is displayed on frontend of store. Try once this.... Someone sure gives answer for this question.

Comment: I think you might be onto something. I listed all images in catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value and they all have a store_id of 1 apart from the image I added manually, which is 0. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57072/discussion-between-rizwan-and-geat).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, I imported the products using csv, my images are displayed in admin but not on frontend.

When I update the product manually from admin, product images start showing that means there was something missing in db that is stopping images to get displayed.

I debug with db in "CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR" table and found attribute_id 155, 156 missing in imported file, 155 is product_page_type=default & 156 is product_image_size = 0, you can eav_attribute table for 155, 156.

As soon as I added these attributes in csv in additional_attribute column, and imported the csv again.

then reindex the magento, clear cache and everything works good.

Thanks 
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to run the following SQL and clear the caches:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value SET store_id=0;
```

As the images had all been assigned to a store_id of 1. If anyone could explain why, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

When you migration finished. Please run index all data:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

After that, pls run resize images:

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

The magento catalog:images:resize command enables you to resize images for display on your storefront.